# SSRS Reports asking for credentials

Tags: reporting-services, reportserver, ssrs-2019

How to remove this, Everytime I close the browser and preview the `ssrs` report. It always asking for a login

[image: How to remove this, Everytime I close the browser and preview the ssrs report. It always asking for a login]

I tried to add `url` in the internet option but its not working, I tried to add `url` in the internet option but its not working

Comment: Setup a database user as a service account and change the data source of the report to use that.

Comment: @aduguid I think this is actually a login prompt for the SSRS portal rather than a datasource issue. It's probably down to browser security settings/group policies.

Comment: When I click the web portal url in ssrs it will popup. When I add the url in internet option, trusted sites it work only in the same server/connection but outside the server its not working

Comment: Anyone resolved this issue? Authentication only appears when I deploy the reports in client side but in my local it works and do not require username and password